# django rest framework API edit function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, django

though I am new to django rest framework, all in all, i get how the posting and viewing works each using jquery ajax to post and angular js for rendering the API json data.

but i don't understand yet how the 'edit' and 'delete' function should be implemented here.

it means i have to load preexisting title and contents to the designated field forms and resave the post into that specific post id.

how can i do that?

and how can i check the permission when executing edit or delete function using either jquery or angular?

please consider the fact that my website is SPA (single page app) that shouldn't require any sort of page refresh.

so these concepts are fairly new to me, and i don't understand how i can manually check the permission using only the API

here is the live site : http://192.241.153.25:8000

Comment: You just need to build two end points for editing and deleting. Then call them from jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use class based views for this. Using class based views you can have different end points for different functionalities, differentiating on Request types.

```
class AView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        pass

    def put(self, request, format=None):
        pass
```

for authentication and permissions do refer to http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication